# D3 PIE chart animate on enter and update angular app

Tags: angular, d3.js, d3pie.js

I am working with a D3 pie in my app to visualise some data. I am able to display data correctly. I just want the chart to animate when it enters. It seems when I change data it animates fine. I have simulated the code here

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kuysd8

The main issue is when I add arcTween in 'enter' it throws an error

```js
const data = pie().sort(null).value((d: any) => d.value)(rawData);
const { height, radius } = this.dimensions;
const slices = this.svg.select(`.slices${this.id}`);

// Inner Slices Enter/Update/Remove (for DOUGHNUTS)
const innerSliceUpdate = slices.selectAll(`.innerSlice${this.id}`).data(data);
const innerSliceEnter = innerSliceUpdate.enter().append('path').attr('class', `innerSlice${this.id}`);
innerSliceUpdate.exit().remove();
innerSliceEnter
  .style('fill', (d: any) => hsl(d.data.color).darker(0.7).toString())
  .style('transition', SLICE_ANIME)
  .attr('d', d => this.pieInner(d, radius.x + 0.5, radius.y + 0.5, radius.z, height))
  .each(d => { this.interpolators[d.data.label] = d; });
innerSliceUpdate
  .transition().duration(ANIME_DURATION * 1e3)
  .attrTween('d', d => (t, i = this.interpolatorFn(d)(t)) => this.pieInner(i, radius.x + 0.5, radius.y + 0.5, radius.z, height));

// Top Slices Enter/Update/Remove (facing up x/y axis)
const topSliceUpdate = slices.selectAll(`.topSlice${this.id}`).data(data);
const topSliceEnter = topSliceUpdate.enter().append('path').attr('class', `topSlice${this.id}`);
topSliceUpdate.exit().remove();

topSliceEnter
  .style('fill', d => d.data.color)
  .style('stroke', d => d.data.color)
  .style('transition', SLICE_ANIME)
  .attr('d', d => this.pieTop(d, radius.x, radius.y, radius.z))
  .each(d => { this.interpolators[d.data.label] = d; });
  // ****** TRYING TO ADD AN ARC TWEEN HERE *******
topSliceUpdate
  .transition().duration(ANIME_DURATION * 1e3)
  .attrTween('d', d => (t, i = this.interpolatorFn(d)(t)) => this.pieTop(i, radius.x, radius.y, radius.z));
```

New to D3 any help is appreciated

Note: Looking for a solution to learn and understand what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this piece of code

```
topSliceEnter
   ....
   .attr("d", d => this.pieTop(d, radius.x, radius.y, radius.z))
```

explicitly says that newly added items will be rendered with the finished state, which doesn't make much sense, if you want to animate something then you need starting point from which you are goint to animate.

Lets say you want to animate chart from `{startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0.1}`. Hope you didn't expect me to refactor all your code, so I fixed the `topSlice` piece:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f7pvyz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
topSliceEnter 
      ......
      .attr("d", d => this.pieTop({startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0.1}, radius.x, radius.y, radius.z))
       .each(d => {
        this.interpolators[d.data.label] = {...d, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0.1};
         // I would refactor this. the interpolation logic looks strange, but still this will make your example animate fine.
      });

topSliceUpdate.merge(topSliceEnter) // merge will make next transition to be applied on both entering and updating elements
  .transition()
...
```

P.S. there are some bugs in your code, wich doesn't handle updates correctly, for example color changes

Comment: Thanks the idea was to merge. This is perfect. Yes I can take it from here. much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve animation would be to initialize your chart slices with some different values than what you have currently initialized them with and then use one of the lifecycle hooks like  ngAfterViewInit() to set the actual initial values. Based on your existing code, something like:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  data = [
    { key: 'inprogress', color: 'yellow', label: 'In Progress', value: 0 },
    { key: 'completed', color: 'green', label: 'Completed', value: 0 },
    { key: 'delayed', color: 'red', label: 'Delayed', value: 0 },
  ];  
   ngAfterViewInit(){
     this.data = [
    { key: 'inprogress', color: 'yellow', label: 'In Progress', value: 3 },
    { key: 'completed', color: 'green', label: 'Completed', value: 18 },
    { key: 'delayed', color: 'red', label: 'Delayed', value: 5 },
   ];
  }

  constructor(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.data = [
        { key: 'inprogress', color: 'yellow', label: 'In Progress', value: 5 },
        { key: 'completed', color: 'green', label: 'Completed', value: 5 },
        { key: 'delayed', color: 'red', label: 'Delayed', value: 15 },
      ]
    }, 2000)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thats a hack. I am looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Below is another `hacky` solution, though much easier to implement. It uses the same idea as implemented by @amishra

In your **piechart.component.ts** change `ngAfterViewInit()`

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.id = `__${Math.floor(Math.random() * 5e10)}`;
    this.init();
    if (this.data && this.data.length >= 0) {
      this.draw(this.data.map(item => ({...item, value: 1}))); // <-- Simply add this line
      this.draw(this.data);
    }
  }
```

The idea is for the user to see equal partitions that animate to the final value

[See Sample Implementation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zkjbdu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpiechart.component.ts)

Comment: appreciate the effort but really looking for a solution to learn and understand what I am doing wrong.